# Where to put commas in my Elasticsearch query

Tags: java, php, mysql, laravel, elasticsearch

I am using this [Elasticquent](https://github.com/adamfairholm/Elasticquent) ES package for my Laravel app.

But I am not sure where I should put commas in the query string. I understand that I must put commas if I have more than one element in the inner array. But does all of the arrays need a comma. Both queries seems to work fine thats why I wonder. I want to do it best practise so thats why I am asking.

```
'filtered' => [
                'query' => [
                    'match' => ['title' => Input::get('query')]
                ],
                'filter'=> [
                    'bool' => [
                        'must' => [
                            ['term' => [ 'type' =>  1] ],
                            ['term' => [ 'state' =>  22] ],
                            ['term' => [ 'city' => ] ],
                            [ 'range' => [
                                    'price' => [
                                        'gte' => ,
                                        'lte' => ,
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
            ],
```

And with more comma signs (,)

```
'filtered' => [
                'query' => [
                    'match' => ['title' => Input::get('query')]
                ],
                'filter'=> [
                    'bool' => [
                        'must' => [
                            ['term' => [ 'type' =>  1] ],
                            ['term' => [ 'state' =>  22] ],
                            ['term' => [ 'city' => ] ],
                            [ 'range' => [
                                    'price' => [
                                        'gte' => ,
                                        'lte' => ,
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
```

They both seem to work. And here is an example of a full query using this package:

```
$posts = Post::searchByQuery([
  'filtered' => [
    'filter' => [
      'not' => [
        'terms' => ['title' => ['impedit', 'voluptatem']]
      ]
    ],
    'query' => [
      "bool" => [
        'must' => [
          'multi_match' => [
            'query' => Input::get('query', ''),
            'fields' => [ "title^2", "content"]
          ],
        ],
        "should" => [
          'match' => [
            'tags' => [
              "query" => Input::get('query', ''),
              "type" => "phrase"
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ],
  ],
]);
```

Also, is it possible to use **3 filters inside a MUST** as i do in query #1 and #2 or can you only put multiple filters inside **should {}**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second version of the query, putting the trailing commas is typically used to indicate additional parameters. As you only have one set of parameters, the additional commas are not required. For example, putting a comma after the `filter =>` block, indicates that you have additional statements to come after filter. Also, why leave additional characters for the parser?

```
 'filtered' => [
                    'query' => [
                        'match' => ['title' => Input::get('query')]
                    ],
                    'filter'=> [
                        'bool' => [
                            'must' => [
                                ['term' => [ 'type' =>  1] ],
                                ['term' => [ 'state' =>  22] ],
                                ['term' => [ 'city' => ] ],
                                [ 'range' => [
                                        'price' => [
                                            'gte' => ,
                                            'lte' => ,
                                        ]
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ], // <=== Other operators to filter on?
                        ],  // <=== Other operations other than query and filter?
                    ],
                ],
```

For your second question, multiple filters can be applied by wrapping them in a bool filter, as per the [docs](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-filtered-query.html):

'

```
filtered' => [
                'query' => [
                    'match' => ['title' => Input::get('query')]
                ],
                'filter'=> [
                    'bool' => [
                        'must' => [
                            ['term' => [ 'type' =>  1] ],
                            ['term' => [ 'state' =>  22] ],
                            ['term' => [ 'city' => ] ],
                            [ 'range' => [
                                    'price' => [
                                        'gte' => ,
                                        'lte' => ,
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ],
                        'must_not' => [
                          ['term' => ['state' => 23] ]  // <=== Additional must clause
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
            ],
```

Comment: But can you have multiple "must" filters as in your example above? I thought I only could use multiple within should

Comment: This is in JSON, but look at the docs:

{
  "filtered": {
    "query": { "match": { "tweet": "full text search" }},
    "filter": {
      "bool": {
        "must": { "range": { "created": { "gte": "now - 1d / d" }}},
        "should": [
          { "term": { "featured": true }},
          { "term": { "starred":  true }}
        ],
        "must_not": { "term": { "deleted": false }}
      }
    }
  }
}